# External drive lost power and derived data folder was deleted; now Xcode project fails build

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

Aloha everyone,

I have all of my Xcode files on an external drive, so that I can just plug in the drive when i want to pick up any of my projects.  Unfortunately, we suffered a power failure, only for a couple of minutes, during a rainstorm here on Oahu.  After i booted everything back and got back in Xcode, I got a series of errors and one warning.  The errors indicate that my project was pointed to directories that no longer exist.  Please take a look at the output and let me know if any here knows how to fix this, or if I will have to create another project and start all over.

[Here is the error page from Xcode](http://crispinworks.com/files/xcodeError.png)

[Here is my directory listing](http://crispinworks.com/files/folderListing.png)

The directories no longer exist, so I can not delete them from the Organizer.  I am resigned to start over with a new project, if necessary, but would rather find a way to fix the issue with the current project.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, backup the entire project folder to another drive, in case you run into more issues.

You should be able to delete the contents of the Derived Data folder without any consequence to your project. After is it deleted, it will just recreate anything it needs in the directory. It looks like you might have permissions issues. You might want to open Disk Utility and verify the drive (and repair if necessary). I would recommend doing this, even if you can delete the Derived Data folder.

Comment: I verified both the drive and the volume on the drive and they are both OK.  I will take up your suggestion to have a redundant copy of all of my project folders.  I deleted all of the project folders in the Derived Data directory (all of them that started with NavySpeak), then attempted to clean the build folder, but no dice.  Do you have any idea as to why I am getting a permission error?  That is what I do not understand. I even created a folder with the same name as the one mentioned in the error message, but again no dice.  This is really puzzling.

Comment: You could try replacing the `Derived Data` folder be renaming the current one and creating a new, empty directory. Without being able to tinker with it, it would be tough to work out the permissions issue. Running `chmod -R 755 path/to/folder` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Alexander,

Thank you for your replies, but I got almost everything working again.  I decided to do the old "Windows trick," namely rebooting the computer.  I am not sure what it fixed, but now I can call up my project.  Not everything works like it did prior to the power loss, but I can get it all working in a little while.  I guess I'll have to get an UPS, although it's not like we lose power a lot here.  In the Philippines, yes, but not here in Hawaii.